# Spell check en-GB not working with Japanese keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, spell-checking

I have a application with richttextboxes with spellcheck enabled. I set the spellcheck language to en-GB and it works when I select the English(UK) keyboard. But when I switch to my Japanese keyboard, which is my main, the spellcheck stops working even though I am not using the Japanese characters in the RTBs.

I tried setting the language for spellchecking the following ways:
1)

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement),
typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)));
```

2)

```
> <RichTextBox xml:lang="en-GB" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"
> x:Name="RtbReason" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70"
> Margin="10,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="270" Grid.Row="0">
>                 <FlowDocument>
>                     <Paragraph>
>                         <Run Text=""/>
>                     </Paragraph>
>                 </FlowDocument>
>             </RichTextBox>
```

I need the Japanese keyboard for translating purposes and almost every other use on the PC, so switching all the time is my last resort. I hope anyone can help me fix this issue.